# Ford Taurus Rear Brake Job: How to relieve spring pressure on emergency brake cable?

Tags: ford, brakes

Doing brakes shoes on 2003 Ford Taurus SE, having problem disconnecting the brake shoe lever from the brake cable. How do I relieve the spring pressure on the emergency brake cable that's at the bottom of the brake shoes?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you don't. The easiest way to get this off of there is to grab the little lead (metal) collet at the of the brake cable with either a pair of locking pliers (like Vise-Grips) with enough force to hold on it, but not enough force to deform it. Then just pull it off of the brake shoe arm. This can be done with regular pliers as well, it's just easier with locking ones.

The better trick is actually getting e-brake cable back onto the brake shoe. The trick I've learned here is to again, grab the end of the cable with a pair of Vise-Grips. The with another pair, wiggle it down around the cable, between the first pair of Vise-Grips and the spring. Then, without crimping the cable yet, push the spring back as far as you can push it (or by pulling the cable out further). Once you have a generous amount of brake cable, clamp the cable with the second pair of Vice-Grips well enough to not slip on the cable, but again, with not enough force to deform the cable. Remove the first set of Vice-Grips and you should have enough room to simply place the cable into the groove on the brake shoe arm. Once there, just remove the Vice-Grips from the cable and let the tension from the spring hold it in place.